# How to identify table one row size?

Tags: sql, oracle

I like to know, how to calculate single row size of a table.

Consider my table has below records.

```
Empid Ename Age    DOB      Salary
10000 BalaS 26  12-03-2015  123456
```

Answer (score 3):

This should solve your issue. Use the length() operator as below. This will give the exact length of characters in the specified column.
This will also take care of **NULL** values, **NULL** will calculate to **0** size :

```
select length(Empid || Ename || Age || DOB || Salary)
from mytable 
where id = someId;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this:

```
select vsize(Empid) + vsize(Ename) + vsize(Age) + vsize(DOB) + vsize(Salary)
from mytable 
where id = someId;
```

Comment: It becomes a bit tricky when the columns are nullable. All trailing null columns take no space at all but when null values are followed by not null value then each null takes one byte.

Comment: The length would be byte or Kb or mb?

Comment: @BalaS:- It returns the number of bytes

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link that explains the vsize(expression) function in detail.

[sql VSIZE(expression)](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/vsize.php)